# How to test your program after updating the OS on Android in emulator?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow

For our android app we have had customers that report the program crashes after updating their system from Lollipop to Marshmallow. The program works fine if they do a clean install on Marshmallow, it only happens when they update.

I am trying to recreate their environment on a emulator. The problem I am encountering is I can not figure out how to install the program on Lollipop in the emulator then upgrade the emulator to Marshmallow so I can run a debugger on the program to see where it actually is failing.

We have no physical devices still on Lollipop that are eligible to be updated to Marshmallow.

What is the process for testing upgrading your OS on android without a physical device to update?

Comment: Do you have crash reporting in Google play?

Comment: EDIT: I am checking on it.

Comment: Always have some means of collecting stack traces and related crash data from production apps. That could be through Google Play, Crashlytics/Fabric, ACRA and your preferred backend solution, etc. I do not know that there is a way to replicate an OTA upgrade of a device's OS.

Comment: I think when the OS update crashes your app then that is the OS at fault here, but if you wanted just test where it fails then having 2 emulator with differernt OS will suffice.

Comment: If there is nothing, maybe https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes.html will give you some clue

Comment: It maybe connected with [backup service](https://developer.android.com/google/backup/index.html) also.

Comment: My suspicion is the change in the security model that happened in Marshmellow. people who upgrade are not getting all the security request set to allowed automatically.

Comment: That's what I also think.

Comment: I would add a checking of all dangerous permissions  in onCreate method of the first activity in your app and notify user if some of them are absent.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Can you include your build.gradle file module level ?

Comment: Recently what I have faced is that including different libraries with different version specification can also lead to run time crashes. For example com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable : 25.0.1 and com.android.support:mediarouter-v7 : 24.0.0 . So make sure com.android.support libraries use the exact same version specification.